# Add tuple in gdbus introspection xml

Tags: c++, dbus, gdbus

How can I receive multiple int32 values, ie when I am receiving one value i need to specify it as type=i ,

```
<method name="foo3" >
  <annotation name="org.dsource.dbus.d.Returns" value="bar"/>
  <arg name="bar" type="i" direction="in"/>
</method>
```

but it is not allowing me to specify as, when I am doing so I am getting the error as expecting value is null

```
<method name="foo3" >
  <annotation name="org.dsource.dbus.d.Returns" value="bar"/>
  <arg name="bar" type="ii" direction="in"/>
</method>
```

then I have tried

```
<method name="foo3" >
  <annotation name="org.dsource.dbus.d.Returns" value="bar"/>
  <arg name="bar" type="(ii)" direction="in"/>
</method>
```

The error message is :

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, '(ii)',
>   does not match expected type '((ii))'

It is giving the error as expected value is ((ii)), What I need to get is I need to change the expected value as (ii).. please give me answer
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it as ,

```
 <method name='YourMethod'>"
    <arg type='i' name='name1' direction='in'/>"
     <arg type='i' name='name2' direction='in'/>"
 </method>"
```

and you can use (ii) tuple format to call the method